# updating npm to latest version without sudo cpanel

Tags: node.js, npm, cpanel

I want to update npm to the latest version but the issue is I don't have Sudo in shared hosting and I get this error :

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/n': Permission denied
```

ihave 10.xxx node npm version 6.9.0 installed in shared hosting namecheap
if there is another way to install the latest version of node and npm in shared hosting that will be great

Comment: Some clarifications would be useful:

For example: What hosting provider are you using? What's the current version of npm that is installed? What have you tried already?

Comment: i`ve updated the post

Comment: You won't be able to update the default nodejs and npm version on the server without sudo access. You can always ask your hoster to do that or you can use Node Version Manager (nvm) and install it under your user and then you will be able to use whatever nodejs & npm versions you need.